# Can't get Bootstrap template working on rails/sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to install a template from getboostrap website onto my rails app.

I can get all the templates to work from the section 'using the framework' but when I try to use the 'custom components' themes they won't load properly - its like the css file is missing or something.

This is how I linked the css files (inside index.html.erb)

I replaced . . .

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="cover.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

With . . .

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="../../assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css.scss" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="../../assets/stylesheets/cover.css.scss" rel="stylesheet">
```

Any additional things I need to do?
Thanks!

Comment: Try using `<%= stylesheet_link_tag bootstrap %>` & `<%= stylesheet_link_tag cover %>` rather than your regular href

Comment: I would advise using the gem `bootstrap-sass` and use the asset pipeline to serve all of this...here is a [simple gist](https://gist.github.com/licatajustin/c0635160fbfad1122fa3) to show what I mean.

Comment: I have gem 'bootstrap-sass' in my gemfile already

Comment: where do I put those two?

Answer (score 1):

Read the instructions of the bootstrap-sass gem and follow their conventions https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass.

In your Gemfile add

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
```

Into application.scss

```
Import Bootstrap styles in app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss:

// "bootstrap-sprockets" must be imported before "bootstrap" and "bootstrap/variables"
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Ensure that `application.html.erb` has this line inside

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Rails helpers for including SCSS since the SCSS needs to be precompiled.

In your layout.html.erb there should be `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>` if not add it.

At the top of `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss` add:

`/*
*= require bootstrap.min.css
*/`

Comment: I don't have layout.html.erb but I have application.html.erb. Same thing?

Comment: Yes that is the same thing it should look like a basic website boilerplate.

Comment: it already has this in   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

Comment: Then you just need to add the part to your application.css.scss